# Single word for creating changes in the composition of a group

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

A team has 10 people working in it. Management isn't satisfied with the team and is considering making changes.

I need a general word which describes any of the following situations:

1. Each of the team members is given an independent position.
2. One team member is given an independent position.
3. Four/Five of the team members are given independent positions.

What is this called, in the following format?

> Management decided to __________ the team.

(This is an example I made up which represents the behavior of the *software* I'm documenting. So **please** try not to give employee/industry specific answers.)

**Split** seems like a good word but I don't think it accurately describes #2, even #3 (because of the lack of proportion in the split).

Answer (score 3):

**Reorganize** might be the word that you are looking for.

> We trained hard—but it seemed that every time we were beginning to
>   form up into teams we were reorganized. I was to learn later in life
>   that we tend to meet any new situation by reorganizing, and what a
>   wonderful method it can be for creating the illusion of progress while
>   actually producing confusion, inefficiency, and demoralization.

[Charlton Ogburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlton_Ogburn)

Comment: @deadrat I will do. I got the (supposed) attribution elsewhere. The Wikipedia link was sheer laziness on my part, I admit.

Comment: @deadrat Actually, it wasn't entirely due to laziness. I was already under the misapprehension that we owe it to Petronius, but I decided to Google it just to make sure. The results that I got, of course, served only to reinforce my ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

Management decided to *[restructure](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restructure)* [MWD] the team

> to change the makeup, organization, or pattern of

Answer (score 1):

The word ***reshuffle/reconstitute*** may work for you.

> Management decided to ***reshuffle/reconstitute*** the team.

ODO:

> **[reshuffle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reshuffle)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Interchange the positions of (members of a team, especially government ministers)
>   ‘the president was forced to reshuffle his cabinet’
>
> ‘The company recently reshuffled its top management team.’
>   ‘Yesterday he reshuffled his frontbench team to bring in new spokesmen
>   on all these subjects.’
>
> **[reconstitute](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reconstitute)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **1.1** Change the form and organization of (an institution):
>   ‘he reconstituted his cabinet’
>
> ‘A fourth was given a supervisory position in the newly reconstituted prison system.’

Answer (score 0):

It's not one word, but the idiom [*to shake up*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shake+up) could work in your sentence: *Management decided to **shake up** the team.*

One of the definitions (and a couple of example sentences) is:

> To cause big changes in a situation or organization
>
> *The company announced that it would shake up top management and cut 1,000 jobs.*
>
> *Every new boss likes to shake things up a bit when they take over.*

The noun form, [shake-up,](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shake-up) has this definition:

> a thorough change of administration in an organization, department, or the like, as by dismissals or reassignments.

This might suit your situation: *Management decided that a shake-up of the team was in order.*

Answer (score 0):

[***reconfigure***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reconfigure)

`to change the shape or formation of; remodel; restructure`

`*(dictionary.com)*`

Your sentence:

> Management decided to **reconfigure** the team.

Note: this word is most often used for inanimate objects, but you can also use it for human systems.  It can be rather charming to use it this way, especially if you work in the computer industry, or if you use computers a lot in your workplace.